# Internet access via USB

Tags: ubuntu, networking, laptop, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share Internet between two computers via USB?](https://superuser.com/questions/69656/how-to-share-internet-between-two-computers-via-usb)

I have a windows stationary, and a ubuntu laptop. Is it possible to connect the two via USB cable and use the stationary computers internet connection on the laptop? If the answer is yes, please provide some guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but from PC (Windows) to PC (Windows) with a special type of cable:

http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Connecting-Two-PCs-Using-a-USB-USB-Cable/248

I am not sure whether this cable will work between Windows an Ubuntu though. Worth the try.

Comment: It should work, provided that the cable isn't using too obscure a bridge chip. On the gateway side, you're still using Windows as described in the link. On the client side, Ubuntu also supports Ethernet over USB (which is how these cables work). TCP/IP works on top of this Ethernet layer, so this solution can even support IPv6.

Comment: @bobster please dont refer link try to post your answer directly

Comment: Slight nitpicking: No, it will not work. The posted 'cable' however is not a cable. It is a device which might just do what the OP wants.