# How can I access the internet connection on a windows machine via usb from a linux machine?

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, usb

Suppose I have a laptop with a linux system with no internet connection, and a windows 7 pc connected to the internet.

How can I use the internet connection of the pc on the laptop, connecting the two devices via an usb to usb cable?

I'm not specifying the used Linux distribution on purpose because it shouldn't be needed for the solution: assume the usual command line tools available in most mainstream distributions.

Comment: I have done this on a Windows laptop connected to the internet via wireless using a crossed Ethernet cable between two hard-wired interfaces, so I see no reason that a crossed USB cable should not work equally well, provided that you have USB networking support on both machines.

Comment: I think it really depends on the type of bridge cable that is used for the connection. They all require different drivers, and that leads me to believe that they have different functionality. Most of the bridge cables I've used tend to be recognized as network adapters, making what you are asking above possible.  

I have however seen some that run completely proprietary drivers and require the software of the device itself to function.

Comment: @Arthur could you specify which cables/vendors you are referring to? Also, what you are saying is that with the right cable I should be able to do this similar to how it's done with a"regular"connection?

Comment: If both laptops have WiFi, you can turn the W7 laptop into a WiFi hotspot. ==> https://www.google.com/search?q=laptop+as+wifi+hotspot&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7MXGB_enUS532&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: i also just found [this](http://superuser.com/q/69656/376608) very similar question on superuser