# Forward internet connection over RS-232 Port

Tags: networking, bridge, forwarding, rs232

I have a Campbell Scientific CR1000 board and have a wireless modem that I plug into the board's RS-232 Port.  In order to save data, I would like to forward/bridge my internet connection from my laptop through a USB-RS232 cable to the RS-232 Port on the board.

I know how to do standard bridging of internet connections, but how would I do it over a RS-232 cable?

The RS-232 Modem is an Airlink raven XT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share Internet between two computers via USB?](http://superuser.com/questions/69656/how-to-share-internet-between-two-computers-via-usb)

Comment: Without more details of how it fits together and what exactly you are trying to do,  it is impossible to answer your question.   I've looked up the CR1000, and I highly doubt you would be able to bridge/route our connection via it.   You might be able to reverse things, and have it connect via another device like a router, which can share the connections.

Comment: What is the end result, you want to connect through the Internet to talk to the board, do you want the board to get Internet access (SLIP/PPP)? Wouldn't it just be easier to either take control of the laptop to access the board, or use something like http://www.ipocket232.com (which are amazing units, I have implemented hundreds in the telephony industry).

Comment: I was hoping just to use an existing system (a laptop or desktop) than to have to buy another piece of equipment but the ipocket seems like what would work.

Comment: @acejavelin If you post your comment as an answer (and no other perfect solution comes along, within the next day), I will mark yours as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two options here are to leave the laptop connected and use some type of remote access to it, such as RDP or TeamViewer, or use a device intended for that purpose such as the [iPocket232](http://www.ipocket232.com/index.php/device-networking/ipocket232/) which would allow you to setup a telnet session to it which then pass it through to the RS-232 port. The iPocket232 is used frequently in the telephony and hospitality industries for interfacing Ethernet/IP networks to RS-232 devices, and I have deployed literally hundreds of them, they are very reliable and configurable device. [Startech](https://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/Serial-over-IP/1-port-RS232-serial-over-ip-adapter~NETRS2321P) and [Lantronix](http://www.lantronix.com/products/uds1100-uds1100-poe) make similar devices, and if you look around there are WiFi to RS232 adapters like [these](http://www.bb-elec.com/Products/Ethernet-Serial-Servers-Gateways/Ethernet-Serial-Device-Servers/Serial-to-802-11-b-g-WLAN-Serial-Device-Servers.aspx) by Advantech.

If using one of these devices such as the iPocket, standard networking and port forwarding applies, you can setup the iPocket232 as a Telnet Server on port XXXX (or the default telnet port), port forward that port to the IP address of the iPocket232 in your router, then from the remote end you just telnet to that port.

There are plenty of other products out there, this is just a few I was aware of, Google could be your friend for more options.